# nmap if port open then run something

Tags: scanning, nmap

Is there any way to run command after then nmap is scanned port and got positive result if port is open, for every ip address, like - nmap found ip with particular open port (when scanning eg. 192.168.1.0/24 port 554) and run something immediately, then nmap is contiuning to scan. If the port is closed or else, contiune to scan.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nmap Scripting Engine](https://nmap.org/book/nse.html) was designed for this purpose. You can write a simple script in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) that will run for every open port (or easily filter to a specific port number or service name). It doesn't run *immediately* after discovering an open port, but for very large scans, Nmap will alternate between port scanning and running NSE scripts so that you get results in a fairly steady stream.

If you want to run some external program instead, you can write an NSE script that uses the `os.execute` function to call that program when necessary.